# How to determine that a partial method has no implementation

Tags: c#, roslyn

Given the case:

```
partial class Test
{
    partial void FooBar();
}

partial class Test
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        FooBar();
    }
}
```

Now getting the `SymbolInfo` from the `FooBar()` invocation gives me a `IMethodSymbol` where `PartialDefinitionPart == null` and `PartialImplementationPart == null`. Is there a way to determine that there is no partial implementation ?

Comment: Have you tried compiling? I assume that there will be an error indicating a non implemented partial method.

Comment: What does the symbol look like if there *is* a partial implementation?

Comment: @AgentFire there is no error in such a situation. All calls to that method are skipped by compiler. *If there is no implementation declaration, then the compiler optimizes away both the defining declaration and all calls to the method.* from [Partial Classes and Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The XML documentation for `PartialDefinitionPart` says:

> If this is a partial method implementation part, returns the corresponding
>       definition part.  Otherwise null.

And `PartialImplementationPart`:

> If this is a partial method declaration without a body, and the method is
>       implemented with a body, returns that implementing definition.  Otherwise
>       null.

This mean that if you're calling a partial method that has an implementation, its symbol will have non-`null` `PartialImplementationPart`. Interestingly, there doesn't seem to be a simple way to find whether a method is partial or not.

Comment: At the *syntax level* there is a way to find partial methods, partial is a `MethodDeclarationSyntax.Modifier`. I agree nonetheless that it is quite odd that there's no `IsPartial` property on the symbol.

Answer (score 1):

A method declaration has to

1. have the `partial` modifier (`MethodDeclarationSyntax.Modifiers`)
2. and (based on svicks answer) have neither an `IMethodSymbol.PartialDefinitionPart`
3. nor an `IMethodSymbol.PartialImplementationPart` to be partial **without** an implementation.

The code below demonstrates how to find *all* partial methods without an implementation in a given solution:

```
foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
{
    foreach (var document in project.Documents)
    {
        var methods = document
            .GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result
            .DescendantNodes()
            .OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>()
            .ToList();

        var semanticModel = document.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;
        foreach (var method in methods)
        {
            if (method.Modifiers.All(m => m.ValueText != "partial"))
                continue;

            var methodSymbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(method);
            if (methodSymbol.PartialDefinitionPart == null 
                && methodSymbol.PartialImplementationPart == null)
            {
                // found partial method without an implementation!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you already have a method symbol and know that your method is partial that's of course a bit of overkill, but I wanted to show how to find *not implemented* partial methods *without* the a-priori knowledge that they're partial.

Answer (score 1):

I was coding the method myself using reference to syntax in `IMethodSymbol` when I tried to look for it and found an implementation in this roslyn github issue[1]. That version didn't work for me as I found `DeclaringSyntaxReferences` to contain only one item, even when partial method had body. I fixed it this way:

```
    public static bool IsPartialMethod(this IMethodSymbol method, out bool hasEmptyBody)
    {
        if (method.IsDefinedInMetadata())
        {
            hasEmptyBody = false;
            return false;
        }

        foreach (var reference in method.DeclaringSyntaxReferences)
        {
            var syntax = reference.GetSyntax();
            if (syntax.Kind() != SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration)
                continue;

            var node = syntax as MethodDeclarationSyntax;
            if (!node.Modifiers.Any(SyntaxKind.PartialKeyword))
            {
                hasEmptyBody = false;
                return false;
            }
        }

        hasEmptyBody = method.PartialImplementationPart == null || method.PartialDefinitionPart != null;
        return true;
    }

    /// <returns>False if it's not defined in source</returns>
    public static bool IsDefinedInMetadata(this ISymbol symbol)
    {
        return symbol.Locations.Any(loc => loc.IsInMetadata);
    }
```

[1] https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/48#issuecomment-75641847